# CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID) returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, windows, process, operating-system, pid

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD GetPID(const char* ProcessName) {...}

MODULEENTRY32 GetModule(const char* moduleName, unsigned long long ProcessID) {
    MODULEENTRY32 modEntry = { 0 };
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, ProcessID);

    cout << "Started looking for module " << moduleName << " with PID " << ProcessID << "..." << endl;

    if (hSnapshot == NULL || hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        cout << "Taking snapshot failed. 4" << endl << "Last error:" << GetLastError() << endl; ;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Modules snapshot had been took successfully!" << endl;
        cout << "Starting modulelist scan..." << endl;

        MODULEENTRY32 curr = { 0 };

        curr.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &curr)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(curr.szModule, moduleName)) {
                    cout << "Found " << curr.szModule << " at " << curr.th32ModuleID << " (PID: " << curr.th32ProcessID << ")" << endl;
                    modEntry = curr;
                    break;
                }
                cout << "Found " << curr.szModule << " at " << curr.th32ModuleID << " (PID: " << curr.th32ProcessID << ")" << endl;
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &curr));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return modEntry;
}
int main() {
     unsigned long long pid = GetPID("Process.exe");
     MODULEENTRY32 module = GetModule("process.exe", pid);
}
```

I always get `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, no matter what PID is. The `HANDLE ProcessesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL)` is being called in `GetPID` and works perfect. But if we will set `ProcessID = 0`, the output:

```
Started looking for module Process.exe with PID 0...
Modules snapshot had been took successfully!
Starting modulelist scan...
Found MCBEBot.exe at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found ntdll.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found KERNEL32.DLL at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found KERNELBASE.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found ucrtbase.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found MSVCP140.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found VCRUNTIME140.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found VCRUNTIME140_1.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found sechost.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
Found RPCRT4.dll at 1 (PID: 13180)
```

What is wrong? How to get a real module snapshot by PID? Why am I getting `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`? I tried to swith between x86 and x64 - did not help.

**Function `GetPID()` returns right PID.**

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: You have this condition `if (hSnapshot == NULL || hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {` and call `Module32First(hSnapshot /* Srsly?!? */, &modEntry);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that's not the problem, that line is excess. But thanks for pointing!

Comment: And what makes you sure that this isn't the problem? Elaborate about that in your quesiton please. That's an important fact. Better yet, remove everything irrelevant, and provide a [mcve] as it's required here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, because if it reaches that code that means that it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. That is not supposed to be. I  got the problem in `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID)`, other I can fix easily. That's why I am here :)

Comment: Wild guess: `strcmp("Process.exe", "process.exe") != 0` - Perhaps that's a later problem ... Well, make a [mre] as @πάνταῥεῖ mentioned, and someone will probably spot the error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, that's not the problem either. Just if `hSnapshot` will not be made properly, code you mentioned even will not be executed.

Comment: @Genken Better use your debugger, and step through line by line. Check variable values at every single step.

Comment: As I said, that's perhaps a later problem. Make a [mre] so we get the full picture you have.

Comment: Btw, what did `GetLastError()` return? Btw, you should _only_ check `if(hSnapshot  == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`, not `if (hSnapshot == NULL || hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` since `NULL` is not an indication of error.

Answer (score 0):

I had rebuilt the code, this helped!

```
MODULEENTRY32 GetModule(const char* ModuleName, unsigned long long ProcessID) {
    HANDLE ModuleSnapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry;

    ModuleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessID);
    if (ModuleSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {cout << "Failed while snapshotting modules. 4" << endl; return ModuleEntry; system("pause");}
    ModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    cout << "Sanning for modules on PID " << ProcessID << "..." << endl;

    Module32First(ModuleSnapshot, &ModuleEntry);
    while (true) {
        cout << "Found module: \"" << ModuleEntry.szModule << "\" at " << ModuleEntry.th32ModuleID <<" (PID: " << ModuleEntry.th32ProcessID << ")" << endl;
        if (!strcmp(ModuleEntry.szModule, ModuleName) && ModuleEntry.th32ModuleID == 1) {break;}
        Module32Next(ModuleSnapshot, &ModuleEntry);
    }

    CloseHandle(ModuleSnapshot);
    return ModuleEntry;
}
```

P. S. `while (true) {...}` construction is rather dangerous, do not use that!

Comment: "_do not use that_" - Indeed. Use `if(Module32First(..)) { do { ... } while(Module32Next(..)); }` instead